# How can I export huge tables from SQL (SSMS) to a (compressed) file?

Tags: sql-server, export, ssms

I am working on SSMS v17.5 and have several very large tables (around 200 GB storage, 350 million rows) in my data base.I would like to save some storage on the data base by exporting some of them to a network drive. 
The export wizard does not seem to give the option to export directly to a compressed file, is there a possibility to do that with bcp? Or is it possible to export the data to a different file type? How much space would that take (more or less than in DB?) 
It needs to be possible to reimport the data to the SQL db if needed.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Based on your numbers, are these wide rows? Or do they have a lot of secondary indexes? Maybe they're fragmented?

Comment: The tables have around 100 columns and most of them are not indexed at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can first shrink the DB (if you don't need the log) and then do the backup using compression as the following:

*Shrink*:

```
use [DbName]
ALTER DATABASE [DbName] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE ([DbName_log], 5)
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DbName] SET RECOVERY FULL
```

*Backup with compression*:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [DbName] TO DISK=BackupName WITH Compression
```

Comment: Thanks, can I also do that for single tables somehow?

Comment: No, this is database level backup. For table level backup you can use the `generate script` feature of SSMS that exports a script file (text file) containing the schema and data of specified tables and then you can compress the script file using a compression tool like winrar.

Comment: @cOlumbiA you can implement page or row compression

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible but you can implement data compression described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/data-compression?view=sql-server-2017) and compress the file by another utility like Winrar, 7z or another one. For instance, you can use the code posted [here](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?483660-Trick-Compress-file-using-SQL-Server)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I read the compression doc it says that for row/page compression the table must not exceed the maximum row size of 8060 bytes. Unfortunately I have lots of columns in varchar(max) format so this will not work and i would have to use a columnstore index to compress the table? And then I could run the code snippet to export and zip the file? Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: @cOlumbiA I have never used a columnstore index to compress the table so can't help with it. But you have to run a code snippet to export into a zip file because the SQL server doesn't have default tools for it.